# Adler Machzor still in print?

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, chagim-holidays

Is it still possible to find new printings of the Adler machzorim, in particular those for the three festivals (Chag hamatzot, chag hashavuot, v'chag hasukkot [Re'eh maftir, forget actual citation])?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Amazing-Machzor-English-Ashkenaz-Complete/dp/B003LZNFSK - very expensive!

Comment: @GershonGold, I'm not sure how accurate a source third-party sellers on Amazon are, for price info or availability. But yes: very expensive. (I also have the first two volumes, making it somewhat redundant)

Comment: Is Adler related to Routledge?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, it's the machzor edited and translated by Herbert Adler and ploni Davis, I believe that it is identical, although having never seen a Routledge, I couldn't say.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't quite in print, but you can see the Rosh Hashanah one in full here: http://hebrewbooks.org/42793

The others may be online, too.

Comment: AdinaLeba, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for posting this answer! I hope you'll look around and find other material of interest, perhaps starting with our 150 other [tag:prayer-book] questions. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, to [enable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be in print. But I did find this:

Service of the Synagogue

George Routledge (Author)

3 volumes, New Year (1) / Day of Atonement (2)

For a picture see: http://www.manorhousebooks.co.uk/PICS/IMG_0764.JPG