# Western Ashkenazi machzor

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, chagim-holidays

OK, I know we've got the Rödelheim and the Adler machzorim which typically adhere to Western Ashkenazi minhag, but the former is [prohibitively expensive](http://www.goldschmidt-basel.ch/gebetbuecher/rosch-haschana-und-jom-kippur/machsor-englisch-saemtliche-feiertage.php) and the latter [appears to be out of print](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44610/adler-machzor-still-in-print). Taking this into account, are there any western Ashkenaz machzorim which are still in print within an affordable price range?

Comment: Please edit the question to define "affordable" for you. I can afford to ask you this, but it'll cost you a pretty penny ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This [website](http://korenpub.com/koren/intusd/tefilla/mahzor-holiday-prayer-book.html?SID=2d4c13da61e9d217ebdff57d7c0f0e5a&nusach_eng=133) gives the range of Koren machzorim including the ones with a commentary by Lord Rabbi Sacks. The blurb reads:

> The Koren Sacks Rosh HaShana Mahzor and the Koren Sacks Yom Kippur
>   Mahzor are a pair of Hebrew/English prayer books for the High Holidays
>   with translation and commentary by Rabbi Jonathan Sacks, one of
>   today's leading Jewish thinkers. The design of each book brings out
>   the inner meaning of the High Holidays prayers by aligning the Hebrew
>   and English texts, highlighting key words, distinguishing poetry from
>   prose, and using beautiful fonts created by master typographer Eliyahu
>   Koren. Rabbi Sacks’ translation brings readers closer than ever before
>   to the authentic meaning of the Hebrew text, while his introduction
>   and commentary provide new ways of understanding and experiencing the
>   Yom Kippur service.

The nusach is related to the Routledge nusach and has 
זכרנו לַחַיִים (with a patach under the lamed) instead of the more usual זכרנו לְחַיִים (with a sheva - and [according to the Tur and the Maharam Rothenberg](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_28.html)).

The Artscroll machzorim can be found [here](http://www.artscroll.com/Items.aspx?hierId=LSE&rewrite=165&o=Lowest) .

Comment: I think that the OP was referring to German-origin machzorim, not just any **Nusach** Ashkenaz machzorim. I'm inferring this from the fact that he mentions Rödelheim. Noach, am I correct?

Comment: @DanF, if you can believe it, I only just saw this. Yes you are correct!

Comment: Hi @NoachMiFrankfurt. I also made that assumption from your ID, as well as your having a history of asking man "Yekke-related" questions. Some ideas - eBay? (u never know what appears, there). Many communities have online "shul lists" (they're usually Yahoo groups.) U may want to join a few in NYC area., and place a posting. I know there is a used Jewish book seller in Brooklyn. I'll see if I can locate the name. I'll also check my shuls "shaimos" box. I occasionally find some unusal stuff in there; sometimes "collectors items".

Comment: Found the store - Mizrahi Book Store 3114 Quentin Rd, Brooklyn, NY 11234; (347) 492-6508. The other web site I found is www.jewishusedbooks.com. I went on both web sites and searched for the 2 Siddurim you mentioned. Nothing appeared. Though, perhaps, if you call Mizrahi, he may give you some ideas where to find them, even if he doesn't have any. Just a hunch that there may be a "recluse" Adler siddur somewhere in my shul.

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete Western Ashkenazi siddur available for free online at the opensiddur site: the [*Tefiloh Sefas Yisroel*, nusach of the now gone kehilla of Bad Homburg](http://opensiddur.org/siddurim/ashkenaz/siddur-bnei-ashkenaz-a-german-rite-siddur-prepared-by-r-rallis-wiesenthal/), a city [near Frankfurt, Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_Homburg_vor_der_H%C3%B6he).

It was collated by Rav Rallis Wiesenthal based on pre-Haskalah manuscripts, with the assistance of Machon Moreshes Ashkenaz and Kehal Adas Yeshurun-Jerusalem. Online versions: XHTML, ODT, TXT and PDF. According to the site, one of the major motivations of making this siddur available is:

> his hope that Ashkenazim (descendants of Rhineland Jewry) recover
>   their historic communal and familial customs and traditions. Most
>   descendants of European Jewry including Ḥasidim are descendants of
>   Ashkenazi families ... The survival of these traditions
>   largely depends on the Jews of Ashkenazi descent to honor and preserve
>   these traditions.

Easiest thing would be to download the complete PDF file, print it out and bind it.